# How to implement delete of your post and not other user post in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Lets start off with i am new to programming in rails and trying to learn by building a project. I am creating a project that has following and follower capability similar to twitter... I have implemented the option to delete a post. However, it seems that i can delete other people post as well that i am following etc. How can i implement the delete of my own post and have other user have the ability to edit modify and delete their own post.

## post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 } # 
default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) } # newest tweets / posts first
end
```

## post controller

```
 def destroy
@status_update = Post.find(params[:id])
if @status_update.present?
  @status_update.destroy
end
redirect_to root_url
```

end

## home

```
<%= link_to('Delete', post_path(@p), :method => :delete,data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } ) %>
```

i was also looking at something like this:

```
def owned_post  
unless current_user == @post.user
flash[:alert] = "That post doesn't belong to you!"
redirect_to root_path

  end  
  end
```

Comment: I want to say THANK YOU TO ALL OF YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you have a `Post` model and views all set up:

In your `views/posts/show` you can set up something like this:

```
<% if @post.user.id == current_user.id %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post), class:"btn btn-success btn-sm" %>
<% end %>
```

You will still have a small issue, users can still access the form to edit, so now in your `views/posts/edit` it renders a form so put a condition on it:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <% if @post.user.id == current_user.id %>
    <%= render 'form', tutorial: @post %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <h1>stop trying to edit others post</h1>
<% end %>
```

Comment: yes this is what i did similar to this.... .... what i opt to do as well is to hide the button if evalulation is false... Thanks so much again

Comment: @Randymangal if this answer helped, please accept it as the correct answer, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Good question, though there isn't one single answer I can give you. The question of "authorization" of actions in your app is a big one, and there are gems like [Pundit](https://www.sitepoint.com/straightforward-rails-authorization-with-pundit/) that you could look into for a full-fledged solution.

However, it's always good to start with the basics on your own and build up to a bigger solution. What you have already isn't wrong -- just add `before_action :owned_post, only: [:delete]` (perhaps rename to `ensure_post_owner` or such) to your controller to enforce your rule.

Another option is to scope your ActiveRecord queries to the set of objects your current user is allowed to operate on. So instead of `@post = Post.find(params[:id])`, you could do, `@post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])`. If the user tries to modify a post they don't own, they'll get back a 404 as if that post simply doesn't exist. This can be a good strategy to avoid letting attackers enumerate which posts are and aren't in your database.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help

Answer (score 1):

On view specify something like this:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.id == @post.user_id %>
 # something like edit. links... delete links..
<% end %>
```

or you can also use gem like: cancancan

Comment: This is also right and a short form of the previous answer of the question.